# How to get the id of ext window 

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs, user-controls, ext.net

I have an aspx page with a usercontrol in it . An ext:Window is placed in the user control

```
<ext:Window Hidden="true" AutoScroll="false" Closable="true"  
    HideParent="true" Modal="true" Resizable="false" Header="true" runat="server" ID="tswindow"
```

I want to show this window using  a javascript call  .

```
var window = Ext.getCmp('<%= tswindow.ClientID %>');  
window.show();
```

I am getting the folowing error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'show'

Comment: This would suggest that the Ext.getCmp call has failed, can you debug this and see what 'window' is set to at this point?

Comment: The code you have posted appears to be correct. There are no obvious errors. Posting a full .aspx (.ascx) sample demonstrating how to reproduce the problem will help.

Comment: As well, if you are using the default Ext.NET settings, then you will not require the call to Ext.getCmp. You can just reference an instance of the Window directly by using it's .ClientID. 

Example

<%= tswindow.ClientID %>.show();

Comment: Did these answers help you? Or you need more detailed answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this may works.
Define Id="my_window" in window config.Then to get the window object `Ext.getCmp('my_window').show();`